# Custom Pattern Layout in log4j is not getting used

Tags: java, log4j

I am trying to create a custom layout in log4j as mentioned in this [article](http://www.wideskills.com/log4j-tutorial/10-custom-appender-and-layout-in-log4j).

I created a simple `CustomLayout` like below -

```
public class CustomLayout extends PatternLayout {
    public String format(LoggingEvent event)
    {
        return "Custom Layout";
    }
}
```

A simple custom appender looks like below

```
public class DummyAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {

    private int port;   
    private String apiKey;

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public String getApiKey() {
        return apiKey;
    }

    public void setApiKey(String apiKey) {
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
    }

    public void close() {
    }

    public boolean requiresLayout() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void append(LoggingEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("Logging from Appender " + arg0.getMessage() + " stack");
        ThrowableInformation t = arg0.getThrowableInformation();
        if(t != null) {
            System.out.println("Logging from Appender " + Arrays.asList(t.getThrowableStrRep()).size());
        }
    }
}
```

`log4j.xml` is like below

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="dummyAppender" class="com.log.DummyAppender">
        <param name="Port" value="1234" />
        <param name="ApiKey" value="ABCDEGH" />
        <layout class="com.log.CustomLayout">
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="error" />
        <appender-ref ref="dummyAppender" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

The main class is like below

```
public class HelloLogger {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloLogger.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("Hello World");
        logger.error("Hello {}. Are u in {}", "Woo", "huhu", new Exception("huhuh876"));
    }

}
```

On running the main class it seems the CustomLayout is not getting used.

Output

```
Logging from Appender Hello Woo. Are u in huhu stack
Logging from Appender 2
```

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml or dependencies that you have used

Comment: You’re using the old Log4j 1.2 which became End of Life in summer 2015. Log4j 1.2 is known to be broken in Java 9. Please migrate to Log4j2. Creating custom components is much easier and better documented in Log4j2.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the Logger that your are using to get the instance of appender.

Refer to below code.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class HelloLogger {


    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloLogger.class);

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

            String s = "Woo";
            String s1 = "huhu";
            logger.error("Hello "+s+". Are u in "+s1+" ");

    }
}
```

Output is as follows.

> Logging from Appender Hello Woo. Are u in huhu  stack

I would recommend using log4j2 instead of Log4j as u can use it for asynchronous logging which will help improve the performance.

Comment: Appender is fine. I am asking about the layout. The layout is not getting used.